# How to run java program in maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have selenium maven project created. For running the tests I have to run one program that will create `testNG.xml` which contains list of test cases to be executed.
But for that I need to run one Java program which has dependencies on other Java programs.

Comment: where is the concerned Java program located? in the same maven project? in a dependency? an external jar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the maven exec plugin.

Take a look at this http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependency in pom.xml file.
Run command

```
mvn install
```

it will install all the dependency and create .class files.

To run java file

```
java -cp "define all the jar files path separated by ; or :" name of java file
```